# Discrete Convolution Doesn’t Work for Simple Example

Tags: convolution

```
aa[y_, a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_] :=  Piecewise[{{1 - a0, y == 0}, {a0 - a1, y == 1}, {a1 - a2,     y == 2}, {a2, y == 3}}, 0]
a[y_,a0_,b0_,a1_,b1_,a2_,b2_]:=Piecewise[{{1-a0,y==0},{a0-a1,y==1},{a1-a2,y==2},{a2,y==3},{a3,y==4},{a4,y==5}},0]

DiscreteConvolve[aa[y, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], aa[y, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], y, x]
```

```
DiscreteConvolve[a[y, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], a[y, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], y, x]
```

The first convolution works but not the second.. I don’t understand why..

Comment: As the following works: `Do[Sum[a[y, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] a[x - y, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], {y, 0, 5}] // Print; , {x, 0, 10}]` it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @DanielHuber do you know somebody here who works for mathworks? It would be good to inform them I guess. Such should not happen.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you. If I find a bug, I document it and send it to: support@wolfram.com. Have a nice day, Daniel